# Update\Modify an XML file in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I want to know how I can update an XML file in real time. I had this file for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Cars>
        <car make="Toyota" model="95" hp="78" price="120"/>
        <car make="kia" model="03" hp="80" price="300"/>
    </Cars>
```

What should I do to update the price value like this one? :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Cars>
        <car make="Toyota" model="95" hp="78" price="50"/>
        <car make="kia" model="03" hp="80" price="100"/>
    </Cars>
```

I have searched the web but all I found was how to parse, and how to write the whole file using `XmlSerializer`, but not how to modify. Also I have found [this](https://www.google.com.ly/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiircac3s3LAhXJtBQKHcDNAMYQFgghMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mkyong.com%2Fjava%2Fhow-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser%2F&usg=AFQjCNFTZuZm1zyn4F3czsMK1vtrhkxIeg&sig2=DAGC6a_YZgdKcUC8Xi27eQ) in Java but I failed to implement it on Android because I'm very new to the android-xml world.

Comment: There is unfortunately no _simple_ way to update an xml file. One has to break the xml down into nodes and it becomes quite mind-numbing. The link you supplied is a good starting point but supply some of your code in order for us to help you refine it.

Comment: @GregoryNikitas thank you for yr comment , unfortunately all my tries ends with fail so i have no code for writing xml now ,and for parsing i'm using a XmlPullParser as in official android dev way, and it's work ok.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK after long day with search and tries I have reached my Goal using Java's DOM . To modify an XML file first instantiate these to handle the XML:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(context.openFileInput("MyFileName.xml")); // In My Case it's in the internal Storage
```

then make a `NodeList` for all "car" elements by :

```
NodeList nodeslist = doc.getElementsByTagName("car");
```

or all elements by replacing the car `String` with `"*"`.

Now it well search in every node attributes till it fine the `"price"` value of KIA for example:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < nodeslist.getLength() ; i ++){
            Node node = nodeslist.item(i);
            NamedNodeMap att = node.getAttributes();
            int h = 0;
            boolean isKIA= false;
            while( h < att.getLength()) {
                Node car= att.item(h);
                if(car.getNodeValue().equals("kia"))
                   isKIA= true;      
                if(h == 3 && setSpeed)   // When h=3 because the price is the third attribute
                   playerName.setNodeValue("100");   
                 h += 1;  // To get The Next Attribute.
           }
}
```

OK Finally , Save the new File In the same location using `Transformer` like this :

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource dSource = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(context.openFileOutput("MyFileName.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));  // To save it in the Internal Storage
transformer.transform(dSource, result);
```

That's it :) . I hope this will helps .