# pass variable in xml and read out

Tags: android, xml

```
double summe = 11.11;
String XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
             "  <amount> summe </amount>\ "
             "  <currency_code>EUR</currency_code>"
```

I want to overwrite the value sum in the xml.

Comment: Can you give us more information on the context ? The code you have passed looks more like java building xml.

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working? The more effort you put in your question the more effort everyone will put into answering your question.

Comment: double summe = 11.11;
        String XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                "<multipay>\n" +
                "  <amount> %s </amount>\n" +
                "</multipay>\n";
it's about android studio. I have a double and an xml file. I would like to enter the value sum in the xml but I have an error code

Comment: that `XML` is invalid and the `Java` syntax is invalid, too. also `double` is not accurate enough for monetary values... and using German for variable names results in crappy code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a solution in the following thread :
[Update\Modify an XML file in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107697/update-modify-an-xml-file-in-android)

(possible duplicate)